# PostgreSQL is slow on first query execution but hits the shared buffer

Tags: postgresql

I've got some problem with PostgreSQL. When I'm executing SQL query for the first time, it took 6x slower than subsequents, even with a basic query like `SELECT 1`;

```
SELECT * FROM citygps WHERE  name = 'VILLARS' AND  postalcode = '42390' ORDER BY population DESC NULLS LAST, alias_of DESC NULLS FIRST LIMIT 1;
Time: 62.045ms
```

```
EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS TRUE) SELECT * FROM citygps WHERE name = 'VILLARS' AND postalcode = '42390' ORDER BY population DESC NULLS LAST, alias_of DESC NULLS FIRST LIMIT 1;

                                                                QUERY PLAN
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Limit  (cost=8.32..8.32 rows=1 width=1380) (actual time=0.091..0.091 rows=1 loops=1)
Buffers: shared hit=9
->  Sort  (cost=8.32..8.32 rows=1 width=1380) (actual time=0.090..0.090 rows=1 loops=1)
        Sort Key: population DESC NULLS LAST, alias_of DESC
        Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 26kB
        Buffers: shared hit=9
        ->  Index Scan using citygps_name_start on citygps  (cost=0.29..8.31 rows=1 width=1380) (actual time=0.028..0.036 rows=1 loops=1)
            Index Cond: ((name)::text = 'VILLARS'::text)
            Filter: (postalcode = '42390'::bpchar)
            Rows Removed by Filter: 3
            Buffers: shared hit=6
Planning time: 1.951 ms
Execution time: 0.162 ms
(13 rows)

Time: 6.269 ms
```

```
SELECT * FROM citygps WHERE  name = 'VILLARS' AND  postalcode = '42390' ORDER BY population DESC NULLS LAST, alias_of DESC NULLS FIRST LIMIT 1;
Time: 61.286ms

SELECT * FROM citygps WHERE  name = 'VILLARS' AND  postalcode = '42390' ORDER BY population DESC NULLS LAST, alias_of DESC NULLS FIRST LIMIT 1;
Time: 1.279ms

EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS TRUE) SELECT * FROM citygps WHERE  name = 'VILLARS' AND  postalcode = '42390' ORDER BY population DESC NULLS LAST, alias_of DESC NULLS FIRST LIMIT 1;

                                                                QUERY PLAN
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Limit  (cost=8.32..8.32 rows=1 width=1380) (actual time=0.076..0.077 rows=1 loops=1)
Buffers: shared hit=6
->  Sort  (cost=8.32..8.32 rows=1 width=1380) (actual time=0.074..0.074 rows=1 loops=1)
        Sort Key: population DESC NULLS LAST, alias_of DESC
        Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 26kB
        Buffers: shared hit=6
        ->  Index Scan using citygps_name_start on citygps  (cost=0.29..8.31 rows=1 width=1380) (actual time=0.032..0.041 rows=1 loops=1)
            Index Cond: ((name)::text = 'VILLARS'::text)
            Filter: (postalcode = '42390'::bpchar)
            Rows Removed by Filter: 3
            Buffers: shared hit=6
Planning time: 0.384 ms
Execution time: 0.153 ms
(13 rows)

Time: 1.583 ms
```

On both `EXPLAIN` queries, I've got a `Buffers: shared hit=x` but the first query is slow. There's the same difference on server instead of my local PostgreSQL instance. Do you have some explanations and a way to solve that ?

Comment: `Time: 1.583 ms` is supposed to be slow? Are you executing this query in a loop? BTW: `width=1380` is rather large. Is there postgis involved, or do you just have bulky data?

Comment: This query was executed after the first was done, so it's quick. The problem is the first (`61.286ms`). I'm not using loop. Postgis is involved but no used in this query and not used in the index scan. With a `SELECT 1`, I've got : `0.913ms`, `0.593ms` and `0.511ms` (ordered by time)

Comment: 60 ms is not slow if you need to pull 15 buffers (plus possibly catalogs?) from disk.

Comment: Yeah but for a web application, `60ms` is huge for a first query. I lost `60ms` on each page because of firsts queries type...